# pthread_cond_timedwait returns error 454 (freebsd)

Tags: pthreads, return-value, freebsd, errno, condition-variable

I can't find any info about this error on google, so I'm posting here to see if anyone knows.

Basically, my code has a snippet that looks something like this:

```
int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
if ( (0 != rc) && (ETIMEDOUT != rc)) {
  assert(false); // This should not happen.
}
```

Occasionally, my program will crash and the corefile will show that rc = 454.
454 does not map to any of the error codes in errno.h. In addition, looking at the list of possible return values that can be given by pthread_cond_timedwait(), none of them resemble 454.

I've looked into the parameters passed in, but I don't really know how to interpret them or where I would be able to learn how.

```
(gdb) p *mutex
$20 = {m_lock = {m_owner = 100179, m_flags = 0, m_ceilings = {0, 0}, m_spare = {0, 0, 0, 0}}, m_type = PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, m_owner = 0x80a004c00, m_count = 0, m_refcount = 0, m_spinloops = 0, m_yieldloops = 0, m_qe = {tqe_next = 0x0, tqe_prev = 0x80a004f10}}
(gdb) p *cond
$21 = {c_lock = {m_owner = 0, m_flags = 0, m_ceilings = {0, 0}, m_spare = {0, 0, 0, 0}}, c_kerncv = {c_has_waiters = 1, c_flags = 0, c_spare = {0, 0}}, c_pshared = 0, c_clockid = 0}
(gdb) p ts
$22 = {tv_sec = 1400543215, tv_nsec = 0}
```

The internals of "cond" look suspicious to me but, as I mentioned, I have no way to be sure.

Comment: This sounds more like a memory corruption bug or otherwise some code performing undefined behavior somewhere - I'd recommend running the code with valgrind. And do print out the `rc` variable when this happens, just to be sure it's not gdb showing you wrong info. Just to make sure, are the mutex nd cond variable properly initialized and is the thread owning the mutex before the pthread_cond_timedwait call ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Yes, the mutex and cond variable are typically properly initialized. It is only rarely that this crash happens. From the gdb output, I find that the m_owner value does correspond to the id of the thread in the backtrace. As you can see however, m_owner for c_lock in "cond" is set to 0, but I don't know if that's unexpected or not.

Comment: `if (COND) assert (false);` is terrible style! write `assert (!COND)` so the assertion captures the failing condition, rather than telling you that the expression `false` failed. :) `assert (0 == rc || ETIMEDOUT == rc)`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's FreeBSD, we can look at the source to see where you're getting the mysterious 454 return from.  Using the source archives at fxr.watson.org, I searched for the symbol `pthread_cond_timedwait` and the only credible references are in the GLIBC27 code, so we'll look there.

In source file pthread_cond_timewait.c, we see the function `__pthread_cond_timedwait`.  There are three returns; the first is `EINVAL`, the second is the return from `__pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt` and the third is the return from `__pthread_mutex_cond_lock`.  Now that I've given you the tools to find the answer, you can go chase down the rest of the answer yourself.  The 454 must have come from one of the unlock or lock call.

The `versioned_symbol` macro at the bottom of the source file is what makes the local `__pthread_cond_timedwait` call the global `pthread_cond_timedwait` function.